# How to increase the height of the UWP calender date picker?

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox

I have added UWP calendar date picker. Here is the XAML code

```
<CalendarDatePicker Background="White" Grid.Row="6" Width="660" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="48" PlaceholderText="Date of Birth"  Padding="0" Margin="0" x:Name="DobDatePicker"></CalendarDatePicker>
```

But the problem is that I can't change the height of that calendar textblock control(not the pop up). I tried by setting the minimum height, but it does n't work. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CalenderDatePicker has hardcoded value(32) for its rowdefinition in default style. So, You can modify that particular part of the **CalenderDatePicker** default style to change the height.

*//Portion to modified*

```
 <Style TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
    ....
    ....
    <Grid x:Name="Root">

       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="32" /> /* change your value */
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ....
    ....
    </Style>
```

[Screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQEBr.png)

Complete Style for your reference

*//C# Code*

```
 <CalendarDatePicker>
            <CalendarDatePicker.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerForeground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackground}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderThemeThickness}" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
                                <Grid x:Name="Root">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>

                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>

                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DateText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CalendarGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundFocused}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />

                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">

                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DateText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForegroundSelected}" />
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>

                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                                            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                                <ContentPresenter Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                            <CalendarView x:Name="CalendarView"
                                    Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarViewStyle}"
                                    MinDate="{TemplateBinding MinDate}"
                                    MaxDate="{TemplateBinding MaxDate}"
                                    IsTodayHighlighted="{TemplateBinding IsTodayHighlighted}"
                                    DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}"
                                    FirstDayOfWeek="{TemplateBinding FirstDayOfWeek}"
                                    DayOfWeekFormat="{TemplateBinding DayOfWeekFormat}"
                                    CalendarIdentifier="{TemplateBinding CalendarIdentifier}"
                                    IsOutOfScopeEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsOutOfScopeEnabled}"
                                    IsGroupLabelVisible="{TemplateBinding IsGroupLabelVisible}" />
                                        </Flyout>
                                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="Background"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="DateText"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForeground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Padding="12, 0, 0, 2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="CalendarGlyph"
                            Glyph="&#xE787;"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="16"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CalendarDatePicker.Style>
        </CalendarDatePicker>
```